# Platform Preview version of a browser

Tags: internet-explorer-10

What is a Platform Preview version of a browser. I see that IE10 for Win7 is available as Platform Preview, So is it the **whole package of the browser** or **just a preview of the features that will be available with that version**?

Please Suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Platform preview" means "beta" in Microsoft's talk. Well, not exactly, but you can think of it like this.

You can see in the Wikipedia article about [IE10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_10) which lists **platform** / **developer** / **consumer** / **release** previews which are basically just fancy names for what Mozilla calls **nighly** / **alpha** / **beta** version.

It seems that Windows 7 preview of IE10 is going to arrive tomorrow (news buzz).